# Is the ELF format bound to a CPU architecture or not?

Tags: elf, cpu-architecture

If you go through wikipedia it states that "[ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) is flexible and extensible by design, and it is not bound to any particular processor or architecture." Then why are there so many packages like

- elf_i386
- elf_x86_64
- elf32_x86_64
- i586-elf

etc...

Comment: I don't understand your question. The quotation from Wikipefia refers to the storage format, not the platform of the software within.

Comment: Then whats the difference between              elf_i386,
elf_x86_64,
elf32_x86_64,
i586-elf

Comment: Presumably they are for different processors. I don't know that there is a deeper answer.

Comment: The format specification itself doesn't change between different architectures, while the resulting files are platform specific. Otherwise you could run an executable built for amd64 on any ancient CPU. **EDIT**: Diego Elio 'flameeyes' Pettenò's Blog posts regarding ELF might be interesting to you: https://blog.flameeyes.eu/tag/elf

Comment: This is a good link where the ELF format is explained: http://wiki.osdev.org/ELF

Answer (score 4):

ELF is a format and used by many programs of diff architecture. So all diff type of binary program use ELF only and CPU detect the processor/Architecture of the compiled program via e_machine field in ELF format. In ELF file format, different type of architectures have diff flags/value [e_machine field in the header ] to indicate the type.